# Spring boot not able to pull environment variable from AWS EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have a EC2 environment variable defined. I can echo on the variable as `echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE` and get the variable value printed in the console.

Now when I try to grab the same value from my Spring boot app, I am not able to do so. I have tried all the possibilities/features offered by spring boot. None of them seem to work.

So far I have tried:

```
@Value("#{systemEnvironment['MY_ENV_VARIABLE']}")

@Value("#{environment['MY_ENV_VARIABLE']}")

System.getenv("MY_ENV_VARIABLE")
```

I have tried "MY.ENV.VARIABLE" in all three places above as well.

What am I missing here? Why am I not able to grab the variable value in the code when it prints it fine in the echo.

Note: I do not have root access to the EC2 box to change any conf file.

Comment: Dumb question, is your Spring app running under a different shell or username?

Comment: Is the application running as the same user as you are when you login to perform the `echo`? How is the environment variable set in the first place? I once had an issue where an application was put on the user's path via a `~/.profile` of some kind which then required that in order to find the binaries I needed to run `bash -l` when SSH'ing to the machine

Comment: I am echoing as a normal IAM user (not root) whereas for app deploy I am using amazon CodeDeploy service, which I *think* uses root profile.

Comment: I am also having this issue - it works if the string are hard coded but it can't see the env vars in elastic beanstalk. Any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Value("${MY_ENV_VARIABLE}")` Should work just fine.

However, if that `System.getenv("MY_ENV_VARIABLE")` does not work your you it means that such variable is not set in runtime env.

Double check if runtime user has such variable set.